# WS-Policy Specification in WSDL document - .NET

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, wsdl

I have authored a simple calculator Web service using visual studio 2010. I need to specify policy using WS-Policy language (which I need to append with the WSDL document generated for the service).

How can I do that? Should I need WSE 3.0 Settings tool installed for that in VS 2010? Does VS 2010 support it?

I have tried using XMLSerializer but achieved no success. I badly in need of suggestions regarding this problem.

Please help me in fixing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to manually edit policy? In WCF that's not done directly; instead selecting your security policy is is accomplished indirectly by choosing a proper binding and configuring it correctly.

It's very likely that you'd probably be just fine with a properly configured WSHttp binding, but you can certainly use a custom binding if you need extra flexibility.

Comment: I would like to specify QoS properties (like response time, cost) using WS-Policy. How could I do that without manually editing the WSDL document?